# Loading .txt file into textarea Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get the text file into textarea. The result is "http://mywebsite.com/textfile/(txtinput).txt and the text file doesn't load into textarea.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>textbox</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function readBOX() {
            var txtinput = document.getElementById('txtinput').value;
            document.forms[0].text.value = ("http://mywebsite.com/textfile/") + txtinput +(".txt");
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p> Type</p>
      <input type="text" id="txtinput" />
      <input id="open" type="button" value="READ" onClick="readBOX()" />
      <form>
         <textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="70">loaded text here</textarea>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See AJAX - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: You need to get it using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Javascript didn't work for me. I changed to PHP and it's working very well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>textbox</title>
   </head>
   <body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Process.php

```
<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="70"> 
<?php $name =  $_POST["name"]; echo file_get_contents("$name");?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 11):

You have to use something like its posted in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div)

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#open").click(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url : "helloworld.txt",
           dataType: "text",
           success : function (data) {
               $("#text").text(data);
           }
       });
   });
});
```

Read more on the [jQuery Documentation of .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

### Non jQuery

I you do not want to use jQuery you have to use the `XMLHttpRequest`-Object something like that:

```
var xmlhttp, text;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file.txt', false);
xmlhttp.send();
text = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

But this can be read on the SO-Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155960/xmlhttprequest-to-read-an-external-file) or the complete and understandable documentation on [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

*Note: But this is not cross browser compatible, for older IE version you have to use the `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` object*

Comment: Please do not downvote without comment. Additional information about fileaccess from JS can be found on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: I downvote people who answer with jQuery when the asker wasn't using jQuery. It's true he needs to look into ajax, but I dislike suggesting jQuery solely for that.

Comment: Then write in you question that you do not want to use jQuery. I think the jQuery way is the most common and the first approach.

Comment: I disagree. I think jQuery is only acceptable if you're already using it, or planning to. And I think you should only recommend it when you know the asker is using it.

Comment: @JoeSimmons - I have added some non-jquery way of doing this. we need not to discuss. The user had a question and do not want to include jQuery ;)

Comment: Ok. I switched it to a thumbs up :)

Comment: suggest to use $("#text").text(data); instead in your jQuery based solution  for placing value in textarea

Comment: can i change that url to ("http://mywebsite.com/textfile/") + txtinput +(".txt")?

Comment: I think this will work if your source website hosted on the same domain

Comment: I can't take off this. I need to use it. ("http://mywebsite.com/textfile/") + txtinput +(".txt")

Comment: using $("#text").val(data) instead of $("#text").text(data) has the advanatge that the text is set even if the user already modified the text in the textarea.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I load text into a textarea

```
Main.css

.textbox{
         font-size: 12px;
         float  : left;
         height : 197px;
         width : 650px; }


Default.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <!-- Charactor set allowed to use -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <title>Text from .txt file to TextArea</title>

        <!-- External stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <textarea class="textbox" id="Brief" readonly></textarea>

       <script> $( "#Brief" ).load( "text.txt" ); </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

google textarea to find format of text area

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest way is to request the server to return the pre-filled textarea
(Here's an example using PHP):

```
<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="70">
<?php
echo file_get_contents('yourFile.txt');
?>
</textarea>
```

*Note: Something similar can be done with any [server-side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).*

In the meantime, if you need to load it dynamically, your best bet is using an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) approach. Choose which approach is the best for you to code and maintain. While jQuery is a popular approach, you are free to use anything you feel confortable with and probably want to know about [XmlHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) first.

Dynamic AJAX requests with Pure JavaScript can be tricky so make sure that your solution is cross-browser. A common mistake is using XmlHtpRequest directly and failing to make it compatible with older IE versions, which leads to random bugs depending on which browser / version you use. For example, it could look like this (would need to be tested on all targeted browser so you can add fallbacks if needed):

**Pure JS:**

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined") {
    XMLHttpRequest = function () {
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
        catch (e) {}
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
        catch (e) {}
        try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        catch (e) {}
        throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
    };
}

function readBOX() {
    function reqListener () {
        document.forms[0].text.value = this.responseText;
    }

    var txtinput = document.getElementById("txtinput").value;
    var filePath = "http://mywebsite.com/textfile/" + txtinput + ".txt";

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener;
    oReq.open("get", filePath, true);
    oReq.send();
}
```

But if you don't mind to sacrifice some performances to ensure maximum support, you should use jQuery's implementation:

**jQuery:**

```
function readBOX() {
    var txtinput = document.getElementById("txtinput").value;
    var filePath = "http://mywebsite.com/textfile/" + txtinput + ".txt";

    $.ajax({
        url: filePath
    }).done(function(data){
        document.forms[0].text.value = data;
    });
}
```

*Note: jQuery's library is kind of huge, but keep in mind that if you include it directly from google servers, your user more likely has it already in cache.*

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do we still have to go through `ActiveXObject` hell? Aren't all modern browser support `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: For older IE versions on XP and prior, I'm afraid so. On modern browsers that is not any concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    let input = document.getElementById('input');
    
    // load default.txt into input box
    try {
        let fileToLoad = './default.txt';
        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('GET', fileToLoad, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        input.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } catch(DOMException) {
        input.innerHTML = "Error loading file. Maybe related to filepath or CORS?";
    }
});
```