# how to put a text file in a <textarea>

Tags: html, text, textarea

Is there any way to refrence a **.txt** file with a `textarea`? what I've tried so far dosen't work I do **not** want to use php or ajax, just bare html+css+javascript

```html
  <textarea rows="16" cols="100" name="textdata" href ="hokuco.com/home/livedoc/user.txt"></textarea><br/>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020484/loading-txt-file-into-textarea-javascript

Comment: why you don't want to use ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file with javascript (see link) and then add it to the textarea.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446538/2550732

EDIT:

**Javascript:**

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url : "helloworld.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        $(".text").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's what they want

Comment: Put this type of link in `Comment`

Comment: your right I want to refrence my text but also save to it with php

Comment: can you accomplish this with bare html?

Comment: @parseguy:- No you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery and try like

```
$(".text").load("myText.txt");
```

Check the [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)