# How to read text file with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Does any one know to read a text file using XMLHttpRequest. I need to use it to read a .txt file for the inventory of my website.

Comment: By any chance were you referring to this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155960/xmlhttprequest-to-read-an-external-file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the extension of file you get from your website.
As usual the extension is JSON and you need to parse it to text by

```
JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

If it's not you can use simple codes

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
</script>
```